# Sharing files between microservices

Tags: node.js, microservices, seneca

I'm trying to move a project from its current monolithic state to microservices architecture. The project is in Node.js, so I've started looking into [Seneca.js](http://senecajs.org/), especially with its [seneca-mesh](https://github.com/senecajs/seneca-mesh) module. Moving image manipulation (crop, resize, etc.) into a microservice seemed the most sensible first step, since it drastically slows down my application now.

When the application is monolithic, there is no problem in passing certain files into file-manipulation logic — just read it from local storage disk. With microsevices, however, if we keep in mind *scalability*, it becomes more difficult. Of course, I could build an image manipulation microservice, scale it up *within the same host machine*, and share directories I need between it, so they, too, can read from a local disk.

What if I want a truly scalable microservice, that can be run and scaled on *different* machines with different IP-adresses that *don't share the same filesystem*? I thought that maybe I could take advantage of Node's streaming API and send these files back and forth via HTTP or TCP or sockets or you name it.

As far as I've learned, Seneca.js cannot do it *the right way*. Of course, I could send a file from the main app to image manipulation service via Seneca.js like so:

```
fs.createReadStream('/files/hello.jpg')
  .on('data', function(data) {
    seneca.act({ role: 'file', cmd: 'chunk', data: data }, cb);
  })
  .on('end', function(err) {
    seneca.act({ role: 'file', cmd: 'end' });
  })
  .on('error', function(err) {
    seneca.act({ role: 'test', cmd: 'error' });
  });
```

And receive it in chunks:

```
seneca.add({ role: 'file', cmd: 'chunk' }, writeToFileCb);
seneca.add({ role: 'file', cmd: 'end' }, endFileWriteCb);
```

But this approach seems ugly and wheel-reinventive.

Another way would be to come up with some HTTP server and send files as `multipart/form-data` or `application/octet-stream`, like so:

```
fs.createReadStream('file.json')
  .pipe(request.post('http://image-manipulator'))
```

But this means reinventing the framework for microservice communication. All in all, I ask for advice on file sharing between distributed microservices and possible frameworks for this.

Comment: Nice adjective - *wheel-reinventive*. I shall remember that.

Comment: Anton, what did you decide about this? I'm working on something similar.

Comment: @JoshC., I've eventually moved my logic from direct image manipulations to image-processing proxies, like https://github.com/imazen/imageflow. The API receives a file, performs checks (mime type, etc.) and uploads files to something like S3. When the image is displayed to the end user, they receive a url like `https://images.example.org/some-image.jpg?width=300&quality=80`. Imageflow (running on this domain) is set up to pull images from this S3 (if not cached), process it, send to the user and cache it.

Comment: If you're dealing with other files (other than images) I guess this approach also works. API receives the file, uploads it to the S3 and stores a reference to it in the database. Then if you need to access this file you just download it ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ I guess it's the simplest way.

Comment: @AntonEgorov I'm moving towards something similar. It's tricky to draw lines around when data should and should not be shared between microservices. Sharing db tables is probably a no-no, but published files are ok???  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 5):

If you use Seneca I strongly recommend to read [The Tao of Microservices](https://www.manning.com/books/the-tao-of-microservices), by [Richard Rodger](http://www.richardrodger.com/) the author of Seneca himself.

He addresses directly your question this way (Chapter 3 Section 15):

> Bandwith matters.
>
> The networked nature of microservices systems means that they are very vulnerable to bandwidth limitations. Even if you start out with a plentiful supply, you must adopt a mentality of scarcity. Misbehaving microservices can easily cause an internally generated denial-of-service attack. **Keep your messages small and lean**. Do not use them to send much actual data, **send references to bulk data storage** instead. [...]
>
> To send images between services, do not send the image binary data, send a URL pointing the image.

Back to your specific case, you should use a service that allows you to store/retrieve files, and pass only the URL of the files in the messages between your Seneca services. It is not trivial to build such a system in a pure distributed fashion, so I would rather use AWS S3 or equivalent.

Comment: So you are saying: on api gateway should be part for connecting and upload to S3 and after that message with file data should be sent to service?

Comment: No:
- The client communicates only with the API gateway. Only the API gateway can call the services 
- The command/query to upload/download the file metadata (name, S3 URL, etc... but not the data) use the services (small size of message). Then, the client gets the metadata from the API gateway
- The actual data are downloaded 'out-of-the-band' i.e not using the services (too big for a message). Different ways to do it depending on your context:
 - Client downloads directly if it's OK to expose the URL
 - API gateway downloads the S3 file and forwards the content it to the client

Comment: But you need a file data to upload it on S3, so a file data need to be transfered trought seneca message to file service to be uploaded, am I correct?

Comment: Sorry but no :) The file data must be transferred by another transport network because it would congest the services network (which needs low latency to perform as expected)

Comment: Its okay. :) What network I need to use to transfer data from api to service? Is there any example?

Answer (score 2):

If you are approaching a microservice architecture, you should think of a microservice for managing files! Don't stream files around if you are microservice environment.
For example you might create a FileManagerService with an API exposed for with CRUD implementation and only use seneca act/add for serving the important data ... file-url, size, etc..

Comment: Thanks, the only problem is that if it is really a distributed system, I may want to create additional copies of `FileManagerService` for load distribution, then I'll need to have all these services in sync with exactly same data, so I'll have to create a proxy of some kind or upload files to all running instances of `FileManagerService`. As a "bonus" I'll have to write logic to copy all contents of a newly created service from existing ones :) Microservices are becoming more of a pain, than a solution.

Comment: How would one get the file to the FileManagerService, i.e. If a file upload request hits userManagerService, how would userManagerServer send the request to  fileManagerService to handle ?